# node js (-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello World"')

Tags: node.js

I just started to learn node.js and I use macbook pro. In its terminal when I write any node.js command like console.log("Hello World"); its shows -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello World"'. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `node` then press Enter and THEN type `console.log("Hello World")`

Comment: Thank You. I am new and want to learn it so badly. there are so many resources in internet. Feeling confused from where should I start. Would you like to suggest me something?